# Landscape help link broken?

Tags: openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

Doing a Landscape trial.

After logging in https://landscape.canonical.com/account/......

I click on the link [Support]
http://support.canonical.com/

After a couple of redirects I end at
https://canonical.force.com/_nc_external/identity/saml/SamlError

> We can't log you in. Check for an invalid assertion in the SAML Assertion Validator (available in Single Sign-On Settings) or check the login history for failed logins.

What is the best way to log this problem with Landscape?
Completed a form on the website but got no feedback.

Answer (score 0):

As a Canonical customer, You would have access to their support team - see [Ubuntu Advantage](https://www.ubuntu.com/support/plans-and-pricing).

As a Community member, you can report issues here in AskUbuntu, or by filing bugs in [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/).

If you are evaluating a purchase, your sales rep can also help get the team's attention focused on a particular issue.